# ServiceStack formats - XML showing data, others not

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack

When I run this code, the data is not displaying, and I got a blank screen.
If I click `"in other formats: json"` it returns `"{ }"` blank data.

However, it actually has data in it. If I click `"in other formats: xml"` it returns full data.

So, why is my XML working, but my HTML and JSON showing me blank screen?

```
[Route("customers", "GET")]
[Route("customers/{Id}", "GET")]
[Route("customers/page/{Page}", "GET")]
[Route("customers/page/{Page}/size/{Size}", "GET")]
[Route("customers/{Id}/orders", "GET")]
[Route("customers/{Id}/orders/page/{Page}", "GET")]
[Route("customers/{Id}/orders/page/{Page}/size/{Size}", "GET")]
public class Customers {
    public Customers() { Page = 1; Size = 20; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
public class CustomersResponse {
    public IList<Customer> Customers;
    public int Pages;
}
public class CustomerDetailResponse {
    public Customer Customer;
    public IList<Order> Orders;
    public int Pages;
}
public class CustomersService : BaseService {
    public ICustomersManager CustomersManager { get; set; }
    public IOrdersManager OrdersManager { get; set; }
    public IValidator<Customers> Validator { get; set; }  
    public object Get(Customers req) {
        var result = Validator.Validate(req);
        if(!result.IsValid) return result.ToResponseDto();
        if (req.Id == null) {
            return new CustomersResponse {
                Customers = CustomersManager.GetCustomers(req), 
                Pages = CustomersManager.GetCustomersPageCount(req) };
        }
        else {
            return new CustomerDetailResponse {
                Customer = CustomersManager.GetCustomer(req), 
                Orders = OrdersManager.GetOrders(req), 
                Pages = OrdersManager.GetOrdersPageCount(req) };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [ServiceStack's Text Serializers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) only serializes **public properties**, your DTO's have a mix of fields and properties. Either change them all your DTOs to public **properties** or add this in your `AppHost.Configure()`:

```
ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;
```

Comment: You are amazing. Thanks for the explanation. I would never have figured this out by myself.